How to know the permissions used by app from flutter
Is there any way to access the details of apps installed in the device and access its privacy permission details (ex: how much access the GMAIL have in our device?) from the flutter app?
 i used the device_apps in flutter but i do not use that


Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.
